# Amazon Route 53 Alias Record / Zone File not working - external domain registrar

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, cname

My domain "donite.de" is not accessible.
I am using Amazon 53 with an external domain registrar.

At my domain registrar I have the following Zone File. (The SOA and NS records can only be configured this way)

```
$TTL 7200
@   IN SOA ns-787.awsdns-34.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. (
    2019121606   ; serial
    7200         ; refresh
    900          ; retry
    1209600      ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      ns-787.awsdns-34.net.
@                        IN NS      ns-194.awsdns-24.com.
@                        IN NS      ns-1452.awsdns-53.org.
@                        IN NS      ns-1880.awsdns-43.co.uk.
```

In the non editable view it looks like this:
[image: Domain registrar summary]

And this is my Amazon Route 53 Configuration:

[image: Route53 Config]

However if I type in my domain "donite.de", it says that the website can not be found.
(In chrome its: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

The Cloudfront distribution "d17wesggm9cak6.cloudfront.net" itself is working.

A DNS Checker Tool is showing me that the nameservers are known almost everywhere.
https://dnschecker.org/#NS/donite.de

Sometimes a few correct Alias records also show up somewhere:
https://dnschecker.org/#A/donite.de

The site "https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dns%3adonite.de&run=toolpage"
is giving me the error "Primary Name Server Not Listed At Parent ns-787.awsdns-34.net".
Dont know if it matters.

What can I do to make my domain "donite.de" being accessible?

Comment: NS records changes required minimum 48 hours of time depend on ISP ( Internet service provider)

Comment: Check your ns-787.awsdns-34.net this entry from AWS Route53 whether you added correct or not. https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/dns/dns-primary-server-listed-at-parent?page=prob_dns&action=dns:donite.de&showlogin=1&hidepitch=0&hidetoc=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I had to contact my domain registrar so they change the nameservers manually.